# 2nd Order ODE: Variation of Parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I used Abel's theorem $W=ce^{-\int p(t) dt}$ where in this case $p(t)=0$ so the  wronskian is a constant.

There are 2 ways I know of for variation of parameters. One is where you know that $y_1$ is a solution and you let $y_2=y_1v$ be a solution as well.

The other way is where you know $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions and let $u_1y_1 + u_2y_2$ be a solution as well. Then there is a formula you can use to solve for $u_1$ and $u_2$.

The problem I face is for both methods, you need to know at least $y_1$ or $y_2$ but I don't know either. Please help me figure out how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation

let $y_c=t^m$ then you will get
$$m(m-1)-2=0$$
the two roots of this equation are
$m_1=2$ and $m_2=-1$ 
so the complementary solution is 
$$y_c=C_1t^2+C_2/t$$
here $y_1=t^2$ and $y_2=1/t$

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't realize to use Euler's equation.